# Why would the MPI_Status of a successful communication would report "-1" as source

Tags: c++, mpi

Please look at the following MWE, which shows how what appears to me as a successful communication done using `MPI_Irecv` and `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` reports as its source the integer value "-1".

The example includes command-line output, which is as follows. Affter this lines, it SigFaults as the "-1" index is later on used as the source for a send.

> Hi! (fun2) Hi! (fun1) Hi! (fun1) Hi! (fun2) Sent! 0 Flag was 1, source
> was -1, the error was 0, and statusflag was 0
>
> Sent! 0 Flag was 1, source was -1, the error was 0, and statusflag was
> 0

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <omp.h>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

#include <stdio.h>



const int L = 10;


void fun2(int &ready){
    int world_size;
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    printf("Hi! (fun2)\n");
    // Build
    std::queue<int> Q;
    MPI_Request R[L];
    int buffer[L];
    int response[L];
    for (int i=0; i<L; ++i){
        Q.push(i);
    }
    int i=0;
    while (!Q.empty()){ 
        i = Q.front();
        buffer[i] = i;
        Q.pop();
        MPI_Ssend(&buffer[i], 1, MPI_INT,(int) ( (world_rank + 1) % world_size), 2501, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("Sent! %d\n", buffer[i]);
        MPI_Recv(&response[i], 1, MPI_INT, (int) ( (world_rank + 1) % world_size), i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("Recieved! %d\n", response[i]);
    }

    return;
}


void fun1(int &ready){
    int world_size;
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    printf("Hi! (fun1)\n");
    // Build
    int V[world_size];
    int bigger_V[L];
    const int BATCH = 4;
    MPI_Request R[BATCH];
    MPI_Request R2[L];
    int buffer[L];
    int answers[L];
    int j = 0;
    int atomic_int;
    int statusflag = 0;
    bool first = true;

    int b=0;
    for (int i=0; i<L; ++i) {

        // MPI_ANY_SOURCE is used here!
        statusflag = MPI_Irecv(&buffer[i], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 2501, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &R2[i]);
        MPI_Status status; 
        int flag;
        MPI_Wait(&R2[i], &status);
        MPI_Request_get_status(R2[i], &flag, &status); // This status has MPI_SOURCE = -1 !!!
        int q = status.MPI_SOURCE;
        printf("Flag was %d, source was %d, the error was %d, and statusflag was %d\n\n\n",
               flag, q, status.MPI_ERROR, statusflag);std::cout<<std::flush;

        answers[i] = i*5;
        MPI_Ssend(&answers[i], 1, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }
    

    return;
}




int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int ready = 0;
    int provided;
    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
long MYNUM = omp_get_thread_num();  

    if (MYNUM == 0){
        fun1(ready);
    }
    else {
        fun2(ready);
    }

}
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

In order to compile it I hereby provide the following one-liner:

`mpic++ -fopenmp mwe.cpp ; mpirun -n 2 ./a.out`

Comment: Is the threading necessary to the example?

Comment: I would answer that having processors that are both (simultaneous) senders and receivers is part of the system's core properties, but it might not be strictly necessary for a mwe.

Comment: you should always check `provided` is at least what you expect (`MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `MPI_Request_get_status`:

```
MPI_Wait(&R2[i], &status);
MPI_Request_get_status(R2[i], &flag, &status);
```

Do you see that you have two calls that both have the `status` as output? That's suspicious.

Your `MPI_Wait` already clears the request object (that's why it's passed by reference), so `MPI_Request_get_status` gives junk output. This call is for cases where you want to inspect a status without doing a wait call. You should have done `status.MPI_SOURCE` after the wait call.

Btw, the value "-1" is `MPI_PROC_NULL`. I really wish they made that "-2", but it is what it is. You can also take this as an indication of trouble.

Comment: FWIW, in this case (`MPI_Wait()` before `MPI_Request_get_status()`), I suspect Open MPI would set `flag=true` and then set an "empty" status (and hence the "bogus" `MPI_SOURCE`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Sounds plausible. I'm still wondering if the empty status and/or the fact that the request is invalid can be recognized.